# Correct way to create default object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know the best way of creating the default objects in rails. I have created the default admin of the following way.

app/services/default_object_creation/create_default_admin_service.rb

```
class DefaultObjectCreation::AdminService
  def self.create
    Admin.create email: ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"], password: ENV["ADMIN_PASS"]
  end
end
```

db/seeds.rb

```
DefaultObjectCreation::AdminService.create
```

db/migrate/******************_device_create_admins.rb

```
class DeviseCreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:admins) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
      t.string :name,               null: false, default: ""

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :admins, :email,                unique: true

    DefaultObjectCreation::AdminService.create
  end
end
```

I have wondering if is a better solution because i'm not completely happy having all this objects in the services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not going to be using this logic outside of the initial db seed you could remove the logic from services and into seeds.rb.

Comment: But i want it in the migration too and i think that copy the object creation in seed and the migration, be a good idea, because isn't always so simple